# Not able to remove partition of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am having a problem in removing Ubuntu (it's nothing like I am having an issue. It's just I think I have installed it incorrectly...so I tell you how did I installed....firstly my PC contains 1 Tb hard disk and 256 Gb SSD...so while installing Ubuntu I used the `Something else option` which takes us to the partition to make for Ubuntu with Windows 10 ......
There is drag down option in there in which instead of SSD I choose the 1 Tb HDD where to install (this is probably where some problem have occurred)...
I have attached a picture of my disk management where I am not able to delete my partition...

Just now how can I get my PC back removing all partitions and installing this time correctly...!

Disk 0 is for windows 10 and Disk 1 for Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: You haven't installed Ubuntu. The green partition, the largest one on Disk 1, still has an NTFS (Windows NT filesystem), and not Ext4 which you would have if the installation had succeeded. Moreover, it's still recognized as "D:" by Windows. If you install Ubuntu there, you will lose any data that is on your Windows D: drive.

Comment: but i am able to dual boot to ubuntu and windows 10 .....when i restart my computer it shows the option of ubuntu....and ubuntu is working fine even....

Comment: all the partitons that are showing in DISK 1 expect the green one are the same values while i gave during the partiton...and they are the ubuntu one's....please tell what to do!!

Comment: i don't know much about...just i have to remove ubuntu and keep my windows...please help me to do that..!

Comment: Ok, I was too hasty, apologies for that. You have Ubuntu installed but you showed us a Windows tool, which doesn't recognize Ubuntu. Now you have a string of small partitions on Disk 1. If I were you, I would again install Ubuntu and choose *Something else*. Then I would delete all of the partitions on Disk 1 except the first (the 19.53 Gb one), then extend this partition to fill up the rest of the disk. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: .my basic purpose  is firstly remove ubuntu.....so you mean....i have already installed ubuntu then i use my bootable pendrive to install ubuntu again and in the something else option to delete partition and extend the deleted partition with the deleted one...You said : "Then I would delete all of the partitions on Disk 1 except the first (the 19.53 Gb one), then extend this partition to fill up the rest of the disk " so you mean this thing has to be done in something else option only ? or from the disk management of windows 10

Comment: ....and my issue is also from disk management why i am not able to delete the partition of ubuntu ? why i need to again to something else option and do from there....? i have seen some videos they direclty delete partition of ubuntu from disk management only..why i am not able to do so?

Comment: Yes I would use Something Else for that. And why you can't do that from Windows I have no idea, but that is a Windows problem, not a Ubuntu problem, therefore offtopic here.